# Multi-tenant SPN configuration

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

My customer simply created an App registration on the Azure AD portal and is trying to grant multi-tenant access to the SPN, there's no code involved.

I recommended this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant but it talks about some code changes, can you please advise how this can be achieved?

Comment: Could you include more details about your requirement?

Comment: Any specific details that are required?

Comment: What does `grant multi-tenant access to the SPN` mean? You want to use the SPN in another tenant?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the app registration itself to accept multi tenant is simple. its just a radio button change. as per your article. question is now, if there is no code, what are they trying to connect to the spn/app registration? meaning, what are they creating this app registration for?